# Executing pug from local node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, pug

I'm trying to execute pug (/jade) from node_modules but I didn't find the executable inside node_modules/.bin folder.
I'm using MacOS 10.12.5 and I installed pug through "npm install --save pug" command.
How can I execute pug command from node_modules folder without global installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using pug from a command line you have to install `pug-cli`.

As a local package: `npm install pug-cli --save`

As a global package: `npm install pug-cli -g`

More information: https://github.com/pugjs/pug-cli#installation

Comment: Thanks, I didn't figured out that I needed to pug-cli instead of pug.